# Azure RecoveryServiceVault can't be removed?

Tags: azure, recovery-services

During the free trial, I spent time fiddling and experimenting with azure. Now that we've moved to paid version, I need to delete all of the experimented things as we don't need all of them.

One of those is a Recovery services vault that somehow got something stuck in it's backup usage (see screenshot below)

[The recovery vault as it is now, everything is empty apart from the GRS backup usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moB4y.png)

I've looked in all the settings and can find nothing left to remove. Any storage account that may have been linked to the vault is long gone - it's really the only thing that is left in the resource group. I also can't remove the resource group because of this vault.

Any time I try to delete I get following error:

> Vault deletion error
>
> Vault 'TestRecoveryServiceVault' cannot be
> deleted as there are existing resources within the vault. Please
> delete any replicated items, registered servers, Hyper-V sites (Used
> for Site Recovery), policy associations for System Center VMM clouds
> (Used for Site Recovery) and then delete the vault.

I even tried the powershell commands

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "TestRecoveryServiceVault"
Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Vault $vault
```

(same error as above) and

```
Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Vault $vault -Force
```

(but this one throws an error that parameter -Force doesn't exist, I suspect outdated documentation)

I'm at my wits end and would really like this vault gone. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

Clarification:

There are no tasks left in the vault; only 6MB of data that seems to have come from nowhere, as it didn't get deleted with the tasks. I did not opt to keep backup data when removing tasks.

Comment: have you use DPM server to backup data to azure?

Comment: I have not used DPM server at all.

Comment: I recommend you to create a technical support ticket.Here is the link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request to create support case.

Comment: Created a forum post in stead; bossman doesn't want to pay for support and thus we can't make an actual ticket. (three cheers for cheaping out... sigh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally was able to remove the vault, after clearing the **sql backups** from it through powershell. I'm really surprised NO ONE knew about this and it took so much digging to find it.

commands for anyone else having this problem:

These commands are to first see if anything is in the database backups, then remove it all.

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "VaultName"

Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
```

**VIEW THE BACKUP ITEMS**

```
$container = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -FriendlyName $vault.Name

$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase

$availableBackups = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $item

$availableBackups
```

**REMOVE THE BACKUP ITEMS AND VAULT**

```
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -FriendlyName $vault.Name

ForEach ($container in $containers)
{
    $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase

    ForEach ($item in $items)
    {
        Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -item $item -RemoveRecoveryPoints -ea SilentlyContinue
    }

    Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
}

Remove-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Vault $vault
```

I hope I helped some other people out there who ran into this mess.

Comment: Can't believe that more people haven't encountered this issue and upvoted this answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of service. Hopefully saved you some time on it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete any of the backup tasks in the vault before you can delete it, easiest way is with this PowerShell:

```
$vaultName = "<vault name>"
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -Status Registered 
foreach ($container in $containers)
{
    $backupItems = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureVM
    foreach ($backupItem in $backupItems)
    {
        Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $backupItem -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didn't work. As I stated in my question, I have no tasks left in the vault, but somehow it got 6MB of data somewhere. I tried your answer anyway, and ended with the same error still. I need a way to clear the backup usage, not the tasks.